# what should put in config files django install?

Tags: python, django

I read [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/11/30/starting-a-new-django-18-project.html) but I don't know how to implement the following part:

> First, remove the `os` import and the `BASE_DIR` definition and add the following imports:
>
> ```
> from decouple import config
> from unipath import Path
> import dj_database_url
> ```
>
> Define the `PROJECT_DIR`:
>
> ```
> PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).parent
> ```

I tried the following but it seems incorrect:

```
import os
from decouple import config
from unipath import Path
import dj_database_url
PROJECT_DIR = "/home/diegonode/simple_django_skeleton/proyecto"
```

What is the correct value of `PROJECT_DIR`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just literally put `PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).parent` in you `settings.py` file.

That way `PROJECT_DIR` setting will work even if you move you project elsewhere (other local dir, other computer).